# Optional Map typecasting to child class object

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to write following code where `C` is a child class of `B`. And getValue method only available in `C`, not in `B`. But Eclipse is showing an error in this statement:

```
Optional.ofNullable(A).map(A::getB).map(C::getValue);
```

If it is normal case, we will type cast and write like `((C)a.getB()).getValue()`. How do I write same in terms of an `Optional`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `map(C.class::cast)` into your chain.

```
Optional.ofNullable(aOrNull).map(A::getB).map(C.class::cast).map(C::getValue);
```

You could also combine some of your chain of maps.

If `getB()` never returns null, you could just have:

```
Optional.ofNullable(aOrNull).map(a -> ((C) a.getB()).getValue());
```

To retain the null-avoiding behaviour of the `Optional` if `getB()` returns null, you could have:

```
Optional.ofNullable(aOrNull).map(A::getB).map(b -> ((C) b).getValue());
```

Comment: I had to do map(C.class::cast)